# How do I select a column within an active row in EXCEL to paste on a separate worksheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I've figured out how to copy and paste specific cells, however, I'm having trouble with relative cells copying based off current selection. Here's my code and the gap is where I'm having issues selecting.

```
Sub LogPosition()
Dim rngStart As Range
 Set rngStart = ActiveCell
Sheets("Charts").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A148").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("T" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Sheets("Portfolio").Select
    rngStart.Select
ActiveCell.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Charts").Select
Range("U" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Range("A159").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Sheets("Portfolio").Select
    rngStart.Select


Range("G").Select
ActiveCell.Copy
Sheets("Charts").Select
Range("X" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
Sheets("Portfolio").Select
    rngStart.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean `select a column within an active row`? They are not related to your code.

Comment: They are related. Thanks but i figured it out....                   
```Range("G" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
ActiveCell.Copy```